# Opening a view controller from a push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I cannot figure out how to open a view controller from a push notifications. I'm using Parse.com and the  app receives the notifications perfectly. The only issue is when opened from a push notification, the app just returns to whatever view the user was on before exiting the app.

In my AppDelegate, this is what I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

 {


if (launchOptions != nil)
{
   NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];


        NSString *key = ((NSString*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"option"]);

    if([key isEqualToString:@"2"]){


        StatViewController *statVC = [[StatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:statVC];
        navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        self.viewController = navController;
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;}
}


/*Every other parse info needed i.e clientkey*\
```

Now, when I go to Parse.com to send the notification, here's what I use as json:

```
 { "content-available": 1, "sound": "", "alert": "Testing!!!!!!", "option": "2" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle this method too:

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;`

This is the method that gets called if the app is currently running.

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is what gets called when the app is launched from scratch and is what will get called if your app was closed and the user opened it via swiping a push notification or via tapping your notification in notification center.

Write a method such as `- (void)handlePushDictionary:(NSDictionary *)pushDictionary shouldPromptUserBeforeNavigating:(BOOL)shouldPromptUserBeforeNavigating` that's used by both of them. I have a BOOL to specify that an alert should be shown before navigating to the push in case the user is actively using the app (I don't want to move them to another page without their consent).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying :) I have the first two, the third one I will add because what you said makes sense. RE: my original question, I"m wondering how to open a view controller, when the app is launched from a push notification. NSString isEqualToString? NSDictionary?

Comment: @HalesEnchanted Just what Kyle Robson said above. When the dictionary contains some type of indicator that you've predetermined, you push the desired `UIViewController` onto your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @JaredH Thank you! Alright, I added this to AppDelegate: - (void)handlePushDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary shouldPromptUserBeforeNavigating:(BOOL)shouldPromptUserBeforeNavigating {
    
    if (dictionary != nil){
        
        
        NSString *key = ((NSString*)[dictionary objectForKey:@"option"]);
        
        if([key isEqualToString:@"2"]){ } - nothing happens though :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it gets you closer. Instead of changing the `rootViewController`, we'll just use the existing nav controller that you've (presumably) already set.

```
- (void)handlePushDictionary:(NSDictionary *)pushDictionary
{
    if ([[pushDictionary objectForKey:@"option"] isEqualToString:@"2"])
      {
        StatViewController *statVC = [[StatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatViewController" bundle:nil];
        // Use the existing nav controller
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:statVC animated:YES];
        self.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being incredibly patient with me. Right before I saw this reply, I tried this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if ( userInfo != nil )
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo]; // In didReceiveRemoteNotification, I have the indicator I need like you mentioned in your previous reply. It works (!!!!!!!) Thank you so much.